# Is there a way to know which 1 of 3 (or more) slideshows is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am wishing to be able to turn off the active slideshow and turn on the user chosen one from a button. I had thought to just use the code:

```
 $('div.nivoSlider:not(#c' + id + ')').data('nivoslider').stop();
```

One statement to turn off all sliders.

Or use:

```
 $('#c1').data('nivoslider').stop();
 $('#c2').data('nivoslider').stop();   
 $('#c3').data('nivoslider').stop();
```

The problem is, is that it only works on the slider that is actually running.
then causes an error when it trys to stop a slider that isn't even running.

I guess an error is generated but I don't even know where to look for that.

I am wondering if there is any way of knowing which slider is running. Then I could just run the appropriate statement.

Comment: To see a log of errors you can use your browsers inspector most new browsers have this function (e.g In Chrome right click on the effected element and select 'inspect element' then choose console from the top options.

Comment: Thank you. I checked and I get this error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#c1').data('nivoslider').stop();` can cause an error only if slider is not initialized yet.

So, if you have some slider active on page load, you have to store its ID and then use something like:

```
var runningSlider = 1; /* On page load/slider init */
changeSlider(newID) {
    $('#c' + runningSlider).data('nivoslider').stop();
    $('#c' + newID).nivoSlider();
    runningSlider = newID;
}
```

Comment: Yes I just figured out that, that was a problem. I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined". when I try to stop a non existent slider. I am wondering if there is a way for my script to know which of the 3 sliders is initialized. Then I would try to stop ONLY the one and start another. tks.

Comment: I am going to sneak one more question in for you @Shamil Yakupov . I tried to put the code in place. with this in the on load;  <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#c1').nivoSlider({       effect: 'fade'       }); 
runningSlider = 1; /* On page load/slider init */

});

Comment: <div id="slideButtons">
     <button id="1">1</button>
     <button id="2">2</button>
     <button id="3">3</button>
    </div>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#slideButtons button').click(function(){        
     var newID = $(this).attr("id");
     alert (newID);
     alert ('test of variable ' + runningSlider);
     $('#c' + runningSlider).data('nivoslider').stop();     
     $('#c' + newID).data('nivoslider').start();
     var runningSlider = newID;

});
</script>

Comment: I wanted the runningSlider in onload to be global so that my button function could see it. It doesn't seem to be able to as I get : Cannot read property stop of null, as an error. BTW how do I put code in a comment as code. It seems to only allow me to call it code in the original post. sorry about that.

Comment: You have to declare `var runningSlider = 1;` before `$(window).load();`.